# Oracle Varchar2 column with multiple date formats

Tags: oracle, date, varchar

I have a table (my table ) with a varchar2 column (my_column)  , this column inculdes data that may be dates, in almost every known date format. like
dd/mm/yyyy
mm/dd/yyyy
ddMONyyyy
ddmmyyyyy
yymmdd
mm.dd.yy
dd/mm/yyyy hh:24:ss
mm-dd-yyyy
and so many .
Also it could contains a free text data that may be numbers or text.
I need the possible fastest way to retrieve it as a date , and if it's cannot match any date format to retrieve null

Comment: Another good example why it's an exceptionally bad idea to store date values in a varchar column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Said that this is really a bad and dangerous way to store dates, you could try with something like the following:

```
select myColumn,
       coalesce(
                to_date(myColumn default null on conversion error, 'dd/mm/yyyy' ),
                to_date(myColumn default null on conversion error, 'yyyy mm dd' ),
                ...                                                 /* all the known formats */
                to_date(myColumn default null on conversion error ) /* dangerous */
                )
from myTable
```

Here I would list all the possiblly expected formats, in the right order and trying to avoid the `to_date` without format mask, which can be really dangerous and give you unexpected results.

Comment: I know it's rally dangerous , i receive this kind of data from a free text gathered from different sources.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is: You cannot convert the strings to dates.

You say that possible formats include `'dd/mm/yyyy'` and `'mm/dd/yyyy'`. So what date would `'01/02/2000'` be? February 1 or January 2? You cannot know this, so a conversion is impossible.

Having said that, you may want to write a stored procedure where you parse the text yourself and only convert unambiguous strings.

E.g.: Is there a substring containing colons? Then this may be the time part. In the rest of the string: Is there a four-digit number? Then this may be the year. And so on until you are either 100% sure what date/time this is or you cannot unambiguously determine the date (in which case you want to return null).

Example: `'13/01/21'` looks very much like January 13, 2021. Or do you allow the year 2013 in your table or even 2001 or even 1921 or ...? If you know there can be no year less then, say, 2019 in the table and no year greater than 2021, then the year must be 2021. 13 cannot be the month, so it must be the day, which leaves 01 for the month. If you cannot rule out all other options, then you would have to return null.

Comment: I agree with you it is impossible to guess, but there is no way to tell which format is true, it's a source problem.

Comment: Yep. So be careful which dates to convert. Do you want to convert a string `'01/02/03'` not caring that it can be one or two years or even centuries off? Or don't you want to convert it? Aleksej's solution is good and I upvoted it, because I like it. But in case of ambiguity it will just return one of all the possible dates rather arbitrarily. You should have that in mind.