# Oracle Date in Where Clause give me this error ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE

Tags: sql, oracle, date

sql request is:

```
select DRCR_CR_DT 
from PS_DRCR 
where 
TRUNC(DRCR_CR_DT)= TO_DATE('1/4/2022','dd/mon/yyyy');
```

the type of DRCR_CR_DT is: DATE

DRCR_CR_DT contain something like this : 1/4/2022 2:02:54 PM

thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd expect something different; if date you provide is `1/4/2022`, then there's no `mon` format model in it:

```
SQL> select to_date('1/4/2022', 'dd/mon/yyyy') from dual;
select to_date('1/4/2022', 'dd/mon/yyyy') from dual
               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

When fixed:

```
SQL> select to_date('1/4/2022', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual;

TO_DATE('1
----------
01/04/2022

SQL>
```

---

If that's not it, please, provide sample data (`CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` statements).

---

**[EDIT]**

This is what you were supposed to provide; now I had to do it, based on your comment:

> DRCR_CR_DT is a varchar2 the containt of DRCR_CR_DT is 01/04/2022 00:00:00

Therefore:

```
SQL> create table ps_drcr (drcr_cr_dt varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into ps_drcr values ('01/04/2022 00:00:00');


1 row created.
```

Query: `TO_DATE`'s format model must match data format. If table contains 00:00:00, then format model is `hh24:mi:ss`, not `hh:mi:ss am` you used.

In that case, query works **for this particular value**.

```
SQL> select *
  2  from ps_drcr
  3  where TRUNC(TO_DATE(DRCR_CR_DT, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) =
  4        TO_DATE('1/4/2022','dd/mm/yyyy');

DRCR_CR_DT
--------------------
01/04/2022 00:00:00

SQL>
```

Note that it is always a really bad idea to store `date` datatype values as strings (into `varchar2` columns) because nothing prevents you from storing e.g. `ab/&4/20xz 0a:f8:fi` into a `varchar2` column, and that certainly isn't valid date value. If there is at least one row in the table whose `drcr_cr_dt` doesn't represent valid date, query will **fail**.

Comment: thank you for answering me, so the request you have just proposed to me "select to_date('1/4/2022', 'dd/mm/yyyy') from PS_DRCR" works but when I do it in where clause it does not work.   the request is: select * from PS_DRCR where CUST_CR_DT = to_date(1/4/2022, 'dd/mm/yyyy'); the error now is ORA-00904: "CUST_CR_DT": invalid identifier

Comment: It means that there's no CUST_CR_DT column in that table. As I said: provide sample data, it'll make things MUCH clearer. As is, we have no idea what you really have.

Comment: Hy Littlefoot, now i get this error ORA-01849: hour must be between 1 and 12. my request is select DRCR_CR_DT from PS_DRCR where TRUNC(TO_DATE(DRCR_CR_DT, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')) = TO_DATE('1/4/2022','dd/mm/yyyy'); DRCR_CR_DT is a varchar2 the containt of DRCR_CR_DT is 01/04/2022 00:00:00

Comment: Have a look at edited answer, please.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that `DRCR_CR_DT` is a string, not a real date - so its data type is VARCHAR2 not DATE as you said.

```sql
create table PS_DRCR (DRCR_CR_DT) AS
select '1/4/2022 2:02:54 PM' from dual;

select DRCR_CR_DT 
from PS_DRCR 
where 
TRUNC(DRCR_CR_DT)= TO_DATE('1/4/2022','dd/mon/yyyy');

ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE
```

If it was really a date it would work - at least, with the format model fixed as @Littlefoot pointed out.

If you are stuck with it as a string (which is a bad data model) then you need to convert it to a date before truncating:

```sql
select DRCR_CR_DT 
from PS_DRCR 
where 
TRUNC(TO_DATE(DRCR_CR_DT, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')) = TO_DATE('1/4/2022','dd/mm/yyyy');

DRCR_CR_DT
-------------------
1/4/2022 2:02:54 PM
```

You can also compare with a date literal:

```sql
select DRCR_CR_DT 
from PS_DRCR 
where 
TRUNC(TO_DATE(DRCR_CR_DT, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')) = DATE '2022-04-01';
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=ef6d0a9ccdf443d9f06d44d55a3bb13a)

---

The reason you get ORA-00932 is that before it looks at the actual values involved the parser sees something like:

```
where TRUNC(<some string>) = TO_DATE(<some string>)
```

[The numeric form of TRUNC](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TRUNC-number.html) "takes as an argument any numeric data type or any nonnumeric data type that can be implicitly converted to a numeric data type", while [the date form](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/TRUNC-date.html) only takes a "datetime data type". That means `TRUNC(<some string>)` has to be interpreted as a number.

So without looking at either string to be converted, it knows that translates to:

```
where <some number> = <some date>
```

It's doing that analysis before it does any actual conversions, so it doesn't get as far as trying to convert the date string; when it does get that far that will throw ORA-01843.

Comment: thank you very much for the help, it works you have detected the problem that I had

Comment: Hy Alex Poole, now i get this error ORA-01849: hour must be between 1 and 12.  my request is select DRCR_CR_DT from PS_DRCR where TRUNC(TO_DATE(DRCR_CR_DT, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')) = TO_DATE('1/4/2022','dd/mm/yyyy'); DRCR_CR_DT is a varchar2 the containt of DRCR_CR_DT is 01/04/2022 00:00:00

Comment: Then you have your 'dates' stored in multiple formats - one of the reasons you should not store them as strings. That's really a separate issue to this question (as is the ORA-01843). If you have a limited number of formats, and no ambiguity between DD/MM and MM/DD for example, then you can try different formats; if you're on a recent version of Oracle then [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66256689/266304) maybe. Otherwise search for questions on that subject, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31681941/266304), or ask a new question if you can't make those approaches work.